# Spark-Running Batch Job with 15 minutes interval

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using Scala,
I tried Spark streaming, but if by any chance my streaming job crashed for more than 15 minutes, this will generate data loss.

So I just want to know, how to manually keep checkpoints in batch job?

The directories of input data looks like the following

Data --> 20170818 --> (timestamp) --> (many .json files)

The data are uploaded every 5 minutes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may use readStream feature in structured streaming to monitor a directory and pick up new files. Spark automatically handles checkpointing and tracking for you.

```
val ds = spark.readStream
  .format("text")
  .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1)
  .load(logDirectory)
```

Here is a link to for additional material on the topic: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/spark-structured-streaming/spark-sql-streaming-FileStreamSource.html

I personally used format("text") but you should be able to change to format("json"), here is more details on json format: https://databricks.com/blog/2017/02/23/working-complex-data-formats-structured-streaming-apache-spark-2-1.html

Comment: Hi, I don't understand how to add minute limitation to that? how do I make it to trigger every 15  minutes for example?

Comment: .trigger(ProcessingTime("10 seconds")), this option is only available in writeStream which is probably due to lazy evaluation (as the execution starts when the action takes place).https://databricks.com/blog/2017/01/19/real-time-streaming-etl-structured-streaming-apache-spark-2-1.html